# Procedure for calculating a sampling distribution

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, estimation, sampling, estimators

I'm still trying to understand the basics of understanding the intuition of sampling distributions and calculating the sampling distributions of common estimators. For example, I understand the intuition behind the distribution of the sample mean, where the mean of each sample may not be the exact mean of the overall population, but for a sufficiently high number of samples, the samples should be normally distributed.

However, how would I go about calculating the sampling distribution of something like $\delta(X)=\frac{X+1}{n+2}$? And what would the intuition behind this be?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Quick correction.  The *samples* are not approximately normally distributed, but the *mean of the samples* is.